# Database-specific custom ribbon not loading

Tags: ms-access-2010, ribbon

I've been trying to create a custom ribbon for a database using the guide [here](http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons:Load_Ribbons_Into_The_Database:..._Using_The_System_Table_USysRibbons).

I have the XML for my ribbon (formatted here for reading ease), which includes the custom tab `MyDatabase`:

```
<mso:cmd app="Access" dt="0" />
<mso:customUI xmlns:mso="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
    <mso:ribbon>
        <mso:qat/>
        <mso:tabs>
            <mso:tab id="mso_c5.55CD83" label="MyDatabase">
                <mso:group id="mso_c6.55CD83" label="Sort &amp;&amp; Filter" imageMso="FilterByResource">
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:FiltersMenu" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:SortUp" size="small" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:SortDown" size="small" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:SortRemoveAllSorts" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:SortSelectionMenu" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:FilterToggleFilter" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
                <mso:group id="mso_c7.570112" label="Find" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:FindDialog" visible="true"/>
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:GoToMenuAccess" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
                <mso:group id="mso_c8.57A030" label="Clipboard" autoScale="true">
                    <mso:control idQ="mso:Copy" visible="true"/>
                </mso:group>
            </mso:tab>
        </mso:tabs>
    </mso:ribbon>
</mso:customUI>
```

And have created the `USysRibbons` table as described and added the ribbon to it. I've gone to set the ribbon up to appear for this database (`File` -> `Options` -> `Current Database` -> `Ribbon and Toolbar Options` -> `Ribbon Name: MyDatabase`).

However, on restarting the database, my custom ribbon **does not appear** (although it is still selected in the `Current Database` tab). The standard ribbon (without my tab) loads instead. Any idea why?

> **Note:** This needs to be a ribbon specific to *this database* that will appear on any computer that loads it. Not a ribbon that appears on all databases only on this instance of Access (which is what the `Customize Ribbon` button provides)

Answer (score 7):

Solved it - A couple of things to note here:

1. **Turn on UI errors** - This will tell you *why* the ribbon couldn't load. Go to `File` -> `Options` -> `Client Settings` -> `General` -> `Show add-in user interface errors`, which helps debugging. Otherwise it fails completely silently.
2. That XML I posted in the question is the XML that **Access itself produces** when you export a custom ribbon. Unfortunately, this `USysRibbons` method **doesn't seem to like its own flavour of XML** (oh, *Microsoft*). Instead, it must prescribe to the format as described [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/customize-the-ribbon-HA010211415.aspx) - essentially remove `<mso:cmd app="Access" dt="0" />`, remove all the `mso:` tag prefixes, and change attributes `idQ="mso:xxxx"` to `idMso="xxxx"`. This is the XML that ultimately works for me:

   ```
   <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
       <ribbon startFromScratch="true"> 
           <tabs> 
               <tab id="MyDatabase" label="My Database"> 
                   <group id="SortFilter" label="Sort &amp;&amp; Filter"> 
                       <control idMso="FiltersMenu" visible="true"/> 
                       <control idMso="SortUp" visible="true"/> 
                       <control idMso="SortDown" visible="true"/> 
                       <control idMso="SortRemoveAllSorts" visible="true"/> 
                       <control idMso="SortSelectionMenu" visible="true"/> 
                       <control idMso="FilterToggleFilter" visible="true"/> 
                   </group > 
               </tab> 
           </tabs> 
       </ribbon> 
   </customUI>
   ```

#### Edit

The settings for number 1 (see above) looks like this in the german version:

[image: Setting to turn on the display of UI errors]

Comment: Weird. The XML isn't displaying in the answer. You can clearly see it in the Edit window though. Can anyone make it appear?

Comment: I fiddled about a bit, and as far as I can see, Stackoverflow objects to the first three lines of the XML

Comment: If I stick a blockquote above it, it show up. Bizarre.

Comment: Never mind, it just needed [indenting further](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216043/266312)

Comment: Thank you for the details.  That 'show errors' option is annoyingly difficult to find even after you know it exists somewhere.